# AADSTS9002327 error in Refresh Token Flow in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, refresh-token, oauth-refresh-token

I am getting below error when I attempt a Refresh Token Flow in Azure AD.

> AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests

My problem is identical to what is shared below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1312290/tokens-for-spa

My HTTP post contains the `grant_type` and `refresh_token`. I tried to include "origin", "redirection_uri" , "scope" etc but I still get the same error.

Is this problem with my HTTP Post message, with Azure AD app registration, or Azure AD itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD SPA application**:

[image]

Granted API permissions:

[image]

**To authorize users**, I used below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ClientID/spaapp.access openid offline_access
&state=12345
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

Generated **access token** by using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://ClientId/spaapp.access openid offline_access openid offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code_verifier:S256
```

And passed **Origin as header**:

```json
Origin:https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

[image]

The error ***"AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests"*** usually occurs if you are not passing origin as header or passing invalid parameters to refresh the access token.

**To refresh the access token**, make use of below parameters:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:refresh_token
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
refresh_token:RefreshToken
```

Make sure to pass **Origin as header**:

```json
Origin:RedirectURL
```

[image]

**I am able to successfully refresh the access token:**

[image]

The scope parameter is optional. If you are not passing the scope, the original scopes will be used. Or you can request a set of scopes.

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

- Make sure the Azure AD application is configured as SPA.
- Make sure the origin you are passing, and the redirect URL configured in the application matches.
- Ensure CORS is properly configured and the server is allowing requests from SPA.

Comment: Great job...It worked for me....my mistake was I send the "origin" in the body. When I send the origin in header, it worked....

thanks a lot